# Как правильно экранировать при передаче по ssh в sed

Tags: строки, bash, ssh, sed

```
ssh ${connect}  "sed -i 's/<!--replacing_base-->/<base href="<?="\/folder\/" . basename(__DIR__) . "\/"?>">/g' ${PATH}"
```

basename(**DIR**) не экранируется
как это правильно сделать ?

Comment: Думаю проще в sed использовать другой разделитель, по типу `..sed -i 's~...~...~g' ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то такое можно сделать, но выглядит хрупко. Другие варианты:

- Стянуть файл -> обработать -> закачать обратно.
- Создать (динамически или один раз скрипт-замены) -> запустить удаленно `sh` и скормить ему скрипт-замены в STDIN на выполнение.

Comment: И для вас, и для @injectCR -- это делается с помощью XPath. Не надо в XML лазать грязными регулярными выражениями.

Comment: Ответ не касaется sed или xpath, он про "сделать с нелокальным файлом".